# Does angularjs automatically create nested structures?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, nested, notation

a bit confused about how to create and reference items in a nested array using angular.js. I was thinking that I could do:

```
$scope.zones = [ {z:'north'}, {z:'south'} ];
$scope.zones.times = [ {t:'noon'}, {t:'midnight'} ];
$scope.zones.times.places = [ {p:'here'}, {p:'there'} ];
```

and angularjs would create a structure in which every zone has two times and every time has two places.

Then I could use something like:

```
<ul ng-repeat="zone in $scope.zones">
    <li>{{zone.z}}</li>
    <ul ng-repeat="time in zone.times">
        <li>{{time.t}}</li>
        <ul ng-repeat="place in time.places">
            <li>{{place.p}}</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

to see the tree structure on my page.

So, does using the dot notation above actually create a nested array of objects? Should I be able to reference them "recursively" as in the directive above? I'm having trouble getting this to work beyond the first two levels.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting up your data correctly.  It should be:

```
$scope.zones = [ {z:'north'}, {z:'south'} ];
$scope.zones[0].times = [ {t:'noon'}, {t:'midnight'} ];
$scope.zones[1].times = [ {t:'noon'}, {t:'midnight'} ];

Etc...
```

Then your HTML should work as expected.

Comment: OK, that was part of the question I neglected to finish with. Does the "child of" dot notation create the hierarchy or do I have to do it manually. Sounds like the latter. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript using `obj.propName` accesses the property named `propName` of the object referenced by `obj`.

Arrays are also objects (in JavaScript), so these lines of code:

```
$scope.zones = [...];
$scope.zones.times = [...];
```

create an array (named `zones`) and give it a property named `times` (which is also an array).

<sub>**Note:** This is JavaScript-specific and has nothing to do with Angular.</sub>

---

This is not what you want. You want to give the `times` property to `zones`' items, **not** to `zones` itself. (Similarly with `places`.)
In order to achieve that, you need to iterate over the elements of each array and give it the extra properties.

```
var places = [{p: 'here'},  {p: 'there'}];
var times  = [{t: 'noon'},  {t: 'midnight'}];
var zones  = [{z: 'north'}, {z: 'south'}];

// Give each `time` a `places` property
times.forEach(function (time) {
    time.places = places;
});

// Give each `zone` a `times` property
// (Each `time` already has a `places` property.)
zones.forEach(function (zone) {
    zone.times = times;
});

// Assign the augmented `zones` to `$scope.zones`
$scope.zones = zones;
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/YDjV4/)**.

---

<sub>**Note:**

In the above implementation, values are passed by reference. This means that is you change `$scope.zones[0].times[0].places[0]`, `$scope.zones[1].times[1].places[0]` will also be affected, since it references the same object.

This implementation is OK if you just want to read values, as it's more efficient.

If you want to be able to also modify the objects, then you need to create copies of the objects and not assign them by reference.</sub>

<sub>E.g., instead of `time.places = places;` and `zone.times = times;`

write `time.places = angular.copy(places);` and `zone.times = angular.copy(times);` respectively.</sub>

---

The resulting `$scope.zones` object will look liek this:

```
[{
    "z": "north",
    "times": [{
        "t": "noon",
        "places": [
            {"p": "here" },
            {"p": "there"}
        ]
    }, {
        "t": "midnight",
        "places": [
            {"p": "here" },
            {"p": "there"}
        ]
    }]
}, {
    "z": "south",
    "times": [{
        "t": "noon",
        "places": [
            {"p": "here" },
            {"p": "there"}
        ]
    }, {
        "t": "midnight",
        "places": [
            {"p":"here" },
            {"p":"there"}
        ]
    }]
}]
```

---

<sub>**Note:**

In your HTML code you reference `$scope.zones`. This is an error !

The corect way is: `zones`

(All Angular expressions are evaluated in the context of the current Scope, thus `ng-repeat="zone in $scope.zones"` will look for `$scope.$scope.zones`.)</sub>